# Accessing char and int arguments

Tags: c, prototype

```
char match (char*, int n);

int 
main (int argc, char *argv[]) {
  char *query;
  int n = 3;
  query = argv[1];   /*argv[1] = "string" */
  match (query, n)
  return 0;
}

char
match (query, n) { ... }
```

I'm trying to access both arguments (query and n) but i'm getting the error: argument 'query' doesn't match prototype and error: prototype declaration

Comment: That's a mess... Could You improve formatting?

Comment: Which line does the error refer to? That's always a helpful information.

Answer (score 4):

```
char
match(query, n) {
```

uses **implicit int** (a K&R and C89 feature outlawed with C99) for `query` and `n`. The compiler treats it as if you had written `match(int query, int n)`. You must *explicitly* provide the types in the function *definition* as well:

```
char
match(char *query, int n) {
```

Answer (score 2):

In the function definition,

```
char
match(query, n) {
```

should include the argument types:

```
char
match(char *query, int n) {
```

Comment: I would compensate too but I've reached a daily voting limit. Consider this a moral +1!